# if x is in list with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, boolean

I have a list which looks like this:

```
mylist = [
          u'x|freq|x:y|||cbase', 
          u'x|freq|x:y||weights_UK18|c%', 
          u'x|freq||y|weights_UK18|c%', 
          u'x|mean|x[0,0.25]:y||weights|JFP', 
          u'x|median|x[0]:y||weights_UK18|JFP_q1'
          ]
```

I want to find an item based on two conditions

```
1. if the item startswith('x|frequency||y|') 
2. and if something exists in between the 4th and 5th "|"
```

Right now I am doing this in a loop:

```
for item in mylist:
    vkey = v.split('|')
    weight = vkey[4]
    if v.startswith('x|frequency||y|') and weight!='':
        chart_data_type = 'weighted'
```

But is there a way I can just do this on one line?

```
if this in mylist: 
      #blah blah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make your own generator, i.e.,

```
def G(L):
    for item in L:
        vkey = item.split('|')
        weight = vkey[4]
        if item.startswith('x|frequency||y|') and weight!='':
            yield item

for item in G(mylist):
    print(item)
```

or use list comprehension (assuming that the input is valid and thus `[4]` does not generate an exception), e.g.,

```
for item in [el for el in mylist if el.startswith('x|frequency||y|') and el.split('|')[4]!='']:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks! decided to go with the simple list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions for this:

```
import re
for item in mylist:
    if re.match('x\|frequency\|\|y\|[^|]+\|', item):
        chart_data_type = 'weighted'
```

But since `x|frequency||y|` is a static text and it comes *directly* before the fourth part which you want to check for, you can do this much faster by just checking the string:

```
prefix = 'x|frequency||y|'
for item in mylist:
    if item.startswith(prefix) and item[len(prefix)] != '|':
        chart_data_type = 'weighted'
```

This basically checks if the character directly after the prefix is a `|` in which case you know that there is no value.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a single line solution:

```
any(map(lambda i: i.startswith('x|freq||y|') and i.split('|')[4] != '', mylist))
```

Above line will return `True` if your list contain at least 1 item that satisfy the condition `i.startswith('x|freq||y|') and i.split('|')[4] != ''`

Explanation:

1. `lambda i: i.startswith('x|freq||y|') and i.split('|')[4] != ''`

is an inline function that checks for your condition. I think it's clear to you how we do the checks.

2. `map` function is used to create a list of results by processing each item in your list with above lambda function. Normally you would pass a function's name as the first argument but I used a lambda (inline function) to keep it even simpler. Its result will be something like:

   [False, False, True, False, False]
3. `any` will return true if given list contains at least 1 `True` item.